# Pandas : Apply converts index values to float while iterating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, integer

I have a dataframe, say

```
data_dict = {'a': {0: 139, 1: 163, 2: 163, 3: 172, 4: 183, 5: 183}, 'b': {0: 400000000.0, 1: 600000000.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 600000000.0, 4: 600000000.0, 5: 0.0}, 'c': {0: 0.234, 1: 0.964, 2: 0.034, 3: 1.173, 4: 0.734, 5: 0.296}}

     a            b      c
0  139  400000000.0  0.234
1  163  600000000.0  0.964
2  163          0.0  0.034
3  172  600000000.0  1.173
4  183  600000000.0  0.734
5  183          0.0  0.296
```

When I am iterating over the dataframe using apply, I see it converts my index values to float.

```
def adder(row):
    print(row)

    
df[df['b'].eq(0)].reset_index().apply(adder, axis=1)
```

which gives me :

```
index      2.000
a        163.000
b          0.000
c          0.034
Name: 0, dtype: float64
index      5.000
a        183.000
b          0.000
c          0.296
```

Q : Why is pandas apply doing that? What can I do to stop this without explicitly typecasting float to int.

Comment: This is an automatic conversion that pandas will do to optimize operations with `row`. If `row` contained both integers and floats, it'd need to be of dtype `object`, which removes most of the gain from using pandas in the first place. Now, having all floats brings a lot of performance power. Sometimes this automatic conversion is not possible, though. For example, if you had a column with string values, then there'd be no possibility other than holding `row` values with dtype=object, and you would see your index with ints.

Comment: what's the solution for my problem?

Comment: Explicitly, do not `reset_index()`. Access the index with `row.name` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, [rafaelc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535611/rafaelc) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73083163/pandas-apply-converts-index-values-to-float-while-iterating#comment129076415_73083163):

This is an automatic conversion that pandas will do to optimize operations with row. If row contained both integers and floats, it'd need to be of dtype object, which removes most of the gain from using pandas in the first place. Now, having all floats brings a lot of performance power. Sometimes this automatic conversion is not possible, though. For example, if you had a column with string values, then there'd be no possibility other than holding row values with dtype=object, and you would see your index with ints.

**Solution** is,
Explicitly, do not reset_index(). Access the index with row.name instead.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this to happen because `pandas.Series` can have only one `dtype` and therefore 'int' is automagically converted to `float`.

As a workaround, this may work for you:

```
for i in df[df['b'].eq(0)].reset_index().itertuples(index=False): print(i)
```

Result:

```
Pandas(index=2, a=163, b=0.0, c=0.034)
Pandas(index=5, a=183, b=0.0, c=0.296)
```

Alternative:

```
from collections import namedtuple
for i in df[df['b'].eq(0)].reset_index().itertuples(index=False): print(i._asdict())
```

Result:

```
{'index': 2, 'a': 163, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 0.034}
{'index': 5, 'a': 183, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 0.296}
```